# How do I add a background in AisleRiot Solitaire?

Tags: gnome, themes, games, desktop-background

I've seen screenshots with different backgrounds on the AisleRiot card game. How do I set one in Ubuntu?

Here is a picture of the background I made in GIMP which I want to use in AisleRiot;

[image]

Please don't take credit for my image if you want to use it, I am planning on implementing this into the default theme of AisleRiot on 11.04.

Comment: That is a gorgeous image, congrats! Can I use it under the GPL3+, giving full credits and copyright to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, I think the built-in method to do this is broken.

You should be able to install themes by going to the "View" menu, selecting "Card Style," then selecting "Install card themes..." .

[image]

See [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-games/+bug/652181) for gnome-games on Launchpad.

Please add yourself to the bug if you believe you are affected.

Comment: Oh I can do that, it's just that the background stays green and cannot be changed by any theme. It also doesn't work if I change the "baize.png" (background image) file manually.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's part of the bug.   I've encountered the same thing.